# MYSQL Query records with same id in Comma

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to write a mysql query. My table structure is as below:

```
===========================
tender_id | supplier_name
===========================
 160001       Tata
 160005       Wilsons Limited
 160008       Tilkom LTD
 160008       DULUB LLC
 160008       DULUB LLC
============================
```

Now i need a help with a query which should produce the below result that is when ever a tender_id has got more than one supplier_name then it should come with a comma. Iam not sure if i can achieve this with a query. i know to get this result from php script but just wanna know if i can do this with a mysql query:

```
====================================
tender_id | supplier_name
====================================
 160001      Tata
 160005      Wilsons Limited
 160008      Tilkom LTD, DULUB LLC
====================================
```

I started with this query below:

```
SELECT tender_id, supplier_name FROM `quotation_items` group by tender_id, supplier_name
```

Comment: group_concat is what you need!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing a `GROUP BY` on the `tender_id` column *alone*, and using `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate suppliers into a CSV list:

```
SELECT tender_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT supplier_name) AS supplier_name
FROM quotation_items
GROUP BY tender_id
```

Note that the default separator for `GROUP_CONCAT` is comma, but if you wanted a different one you could specify it using `SEPARATOR`.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Its working fine. But in some conditions, for example tender_id 160008 has got the same supplier_name twice. But in the comma separated result it should show only once. Is that possible? 160008 Tilkom LTD, DULUB LLC

Comment: @SanjuMenon Just use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT supplier_name)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thank you for your answer. It makes me learn more about details that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [GROUP CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT tender_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT supplier_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `quotation_items` 
GROUP BY tender_id;
```

To avoid duplicate names, just add DISTINCT keyword in GROUP_CONCAT function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| tender_id | supplier_name     |
+-----------+-------------------+
| 160001    | Tata              |
| 160005    | Wilsons Limited   |
| 160008    | Tilkom LTD        |
| 160008    | DULUB LLC         |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    tender_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(supplier_name SEPARATOR ", ") concated_field
FROM my_table
GROUP BY tender_id;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| tender_id | concated_field           |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| 160001    | Tata                    |
| 160005    | Wilsons Limited         |
| 160008    | Tilkom LTD, DULUB LLC   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.